# Cyclotomic polynomials and Galois group

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials

Let $\zeta\in \mathbb C$ be a primitive $7^{th}$ root of unity.

Show that there exists a $\sigma\in \operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\zeta)/\mathbb Q)$ such that $\sigma(\zeta)=\zeta^3$.

I already know that $\zeta$ is a root of $f(x)=x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ and that $f$ is irreducible (By applying Eisenstein's criterion on $f(x+1)$).

Also the powers of $\zeta$ are also roots of $f$. So $\mathbb Q(\zeta)$ is a splitting field of $f$. Now its clear that this extension is a Galois extension, since all the roots are different. But how to show the desired statement?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that $\langle \zeta\rangle$ is a finite, cyclic group of order $7$, so every non-trivial element has order $7$. In particular $\zeta^3$ is another primitive $7^{th}$ root of $1$, hence is another roots of the irreducible polynomial $\Phi_7(x)={x^7-1\over x-1}$. But then as this is irreducible by Eisenstein's criterion applied to $\Phi(x+1)$, we get that

> $$\Bbb Q(\zeta)/\Bbb Q\cong \Bbb Q[x]/(\Phi_7(x)).$$

We now use the fact that the Galois group transitively permutes the roots of the irreducible polynomial in the quotient--if you haven't seen this before, see my addendum at the bottom--hence for any two roots, $r,s$, there is some $\sigma=\sigma_{r,s}$ such that $\sigma(r)=s$. Taking $r=\zeta$ and $s=\zeta^3$ we get the result.

> The key observations for this are:
>
> - that both $\zeta$ and $\zeta^3$ are roots of the same, irreducible polynomial
> - that the Galois group permutes the roots of such polynomials **transitively**.

---

If you haven't seen the proof of the transitive action on roots, it's relatively straightforward:  since $\Phi_7(x)$ is irreducible, we note that if $r,s$ are any two roots

> $$\Bbb Q(r)/\Bbb Q\cong \Bbb Q[x]/(\Phi_7(x))\cong \Bbb Q(s)/\Bbb Q\qquad (*)$$

Then the automorphism of $\Bbb Q(r)/\Bbb Q$ is simply the composite of the isomorphisms. I.e. if the isomorphisms in $(*)$ are

$$\begin{cases}\varphi_r: \Bbb Q(r)\to \Bbb Q[x]/(\Phi_7(x)) \\
\varphi_s: \Bbb Q(s)\to \Bbb Q[x]/(\Phi_7(x))
\end{cases}$$

then we have that $\sigma_{r,s}=\varphi_s\circ \varphi_r^{-1}: \Bbb Q(s)\to \Bbb Q(r)$ is an isomorphism, but since $\Bbb Q(r)=\Bbb Q(s)$ is actually an **equality** for $r=\zeta, s=\zeta^3$ when we treat them as subfields of $\Bbb C$, we see that we may replace "iso" with "auto," and apply the definition of the Galois group as the group of **all** automorphisms of the field.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer! That helped a lot. I just have forgotten this fact. (We proved this already, but in a different way).

Comment: One more question: If I want to show that this $\sigma$ generates the Galois group it is sufficient to see that $\sigma^i(\zeta)=\sigma^j(\zeta)$ is different for $i\neq j$ with $i,j\in \{1,...,n\}$? Are there other possibilites?

Comment: Really? I thought the Galois group has order 6? Since we are considering the splitting field of $x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x^1+1$

Comment: @Epsilondelta oh right, sorry, brain fart. What I meant to say was you note that $\sigma(\zeta^i)=\sigma(\zeta)^i=\zeta^{3i}$ so $\sigma$ generates iff $3\in\Bbb Z/7\Bbb Z^*$ is a generator of the group, which can be verified by $3^3\equiv -1\mod 7$, i.e. $3$ has order $6$ in the group $\Bbb Z/7\Bbb Z^*$, but yes, you can do it the way you say as well, it's just rather complicated to check that in general.

Comment: Can you explain me the connection between $\zeta^{3i}$ and $3\in \mathbb Z_7^{*}$?

Comment: @Epsilondelta exponents of $\zeta$ are the same iff they are the same modulo $7$. Hence

$$\sigma^i(\zeta)=\zeta^{3^ i}$$

In order for this to be the identity automorphism it is necessary and sufficient that $\sigma^i(\zeta)=\zeta$, since $\zeta$ generates the field. In order for this to be true, we need $3^i\equiv 1\mod 7$. So for $\sigma$ to have order $6$, you need to check that $6$ is the smallest, positive integer for which $3^i\equiv 1\mod 7$, but that's the definition of the order of an element of $\Bbb Z/7\Bbb Z^*$ as a group under multiplication.

Comment: Thanks again :). Another question: If I want to see that $\sigma^3$ is the conjugation restricted on $\mathbb Q(\zeta)$ is it sufficient to argue as follows?: The Galois group G is a group with order 6, hence can only be $\mathbb Z_6$ or $S_3$. But G is cyclic. So $G\cong \mathbb Z_6$. So there is just one subgroup with order 2. And it is easy to see that $\sigma^3$ has also order 2. So it must be the conjugation restricted on $\mathbb Q(\zeta)$. Hopefully you can go through it and improve it, if necessary :)

Comment: @epsilondelta you mean "abelian," its not obvious it's cyclic immediately, but the rest of your argument is the same as mine if you look back a few comments