# cyclotomic polynomial

Tags: galois-theory

Let $w$ be a primitive 10th root of unity. Find the irreducible polynomial of $w+w^{-1}$.

I know that the cyclotomic polynomial of $g_{10}(x)=x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1$ but I can't apply the same techniques used in this question ([Cyclotomic polynomials and Galois groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1127623/cyclotomic-polynomials-and-galois-groups)
) where $w$ is a 7th root of unity instead. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(w+w^{-1})^2 = w^2 + 2 + w^{-2}$$
but $$ w^2 - w + 1 - w^{-1} + w^{-2} = w^{-2} (w^4 - w^3 + w^2 - w + 1) = 0 $$
so 
$$ (w+w^{-1})^2 = w + 1 + w^{-1}$$
i.e. $w+w^{-1}$ is a root of $x^2 - x - 1$.

Answer (score 0):

First off, note that the $10$th roots of unity and $5$th roots of unity both define the $5$th cyclotomic field, $Q(ζ_5)$. If $w$ is a $10$th root of unity, then the minimal polynomial of $w$ is:

$x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1$

Note that this is true for $w^5$ as well.

Now $w^{-1}+w$ is $1/w$ + $w$, or using the equivalent definition of $w^5=w$, $w^{-1}+w$ = $w^4+w$. This element generates the minimal polynomial $x^2-x-1$, which defines the quadratic subfield of the 5$th$ cyclotomic field, namely $K = Q(√5)$.